# How to up files with Bitrix24 api

Tags: rest, file, crm, insert-update, bitrix

How can I update a CRM contact field, this field is type file? I'm using the bitrix24 API

I want to update an image of a contact, in the bitrix23 documentation I can't find anything

This is where I am making the request:
{{url}}/{{token}}/crm.contact.update.json?{{paramams}}}

I tried to send a base64 via parameters and also via form-data, the other fields update, but the image does not update.

I don't know if I have to do any process before, to make it work.

Here is an example of what I am sending in the image:
fields[UF_CRM_QR_CODE][fileData] = ["image.png","{{base64}}"]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how it works in JS:
https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/js_library/rest/files.php

For CRM fields need use syntax

```
"UF_CRM_QR_CODE": {"fileData": ["1.jpg", "R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="]}
```

Which tool or language are you using to send the request?
You need to use POST request